# odd behavior setting timeouts inside a function with global references in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, settimeout

Here is the the function and the globals:

```
      $note_instance = Array();
      $note_count = 0;

      function create(text){
        count = $note_count++;

        time = 5000;            

        $note_instance[count] = $notifications.notify("create", text);

        setTimeout(function(){ $note_instance[count].close() }, time);
      }
```

The function simply opens a notification, a sets a timeout to close it in 5 seconds.

so if i call this

```
 create("Good Note 1");
 create("Good Note 2");
 create("Good Note 3");
```

Ecah note should close 5 seconds from their creation, however always and only the last note closes, in this case "Good Note 3".

Each note object has its own entry in the the $note_instance global array so the timeouts should no be overwriting themselves.

What am i missing here folks? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` is a global variable.

You need to change it to a local variable by adding `var count` inside the function.

Comment: Thanks mate, that sure did the trick. But how come 'count' was in the global scope if it was not declared outside the function?

Comment: `count` was never declared with the `var` operator, it was just used for the first time in the `create` function, so JavaScript assumes it has global scope.

Comment: That's how it works in JavaScript - if a variable is not declared anywhere, it's a global. That's an enormously bad idea, but it is how the language is designed to work.

Comment: LOL :) i thought i did and then i remember that for some reason the system didn't let me pick an answer, something about waiting 9 minutes. Odd! isn't it? so i forgot to come back and pick the answer.
Thanks for the reminder.